# Is $x^3+4$ irreducible in $Z_{11}[x]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

What are the factors if it is not?  I am not sure how to figure this out in regards to $Z_{11}[x]$.

Comment: Does the equation $x^3 \equiv -4 \pmod{11}$ have a solution?

Comment: (-5)^3 = 4 mod 11, if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 2):

Over any field, a cubic is irreducible if and only if it has no roots.

You can just check whether this has any roots over $\mathbb{Z}_{11}$.

As TMM points out in the comments, $6$ is a root. Therefore $x^3+4$ is reducible over $\mathbb{Z}_{11}$.

---

You can use the divison algorithm (remembering that you are working mod $11$) to get that:

$$ x^3 + 4 \equiv (x-6)(x^2+6x + 3). $$

You can then see if $x^2+6x + 3$ has any roots to factor further.

Comment: Discriminant of $x^2 + 6x + 3$ is $36 - 12 = 24$, and $\sqrt{24} = 2\sqrt{6}$. But no element of $\mathbb{Z}_{11}$ squared yields $6$.

Comment: Given the experience level of the poster, I think that telling them to plug in is a better idea. Besides, checking that $\sqrt{6}$ does not exist in $\mathbb{Z}_{11}$ involves checking every element of $\mathbb{Z}_{11}$ anyway... so you haven't saved any effort.

Comment: My comment was only intended to mean, "there are no further roots, which I know because I *did* check every element of $\mathbb{Z}_{11}$."